# Unknown provenance of <a></a> tag

Tags: php, html

In next DIV tag there is php code to echo "$statuslist" variable

```
<div id="statusarea">
      <?php echo $statuslist;?>
    </div>
```

and code below  is showing what "$statuslist" does content. The first element is DIV element, but the browser is displaying "a" tag. Also then before first child DIV there is another "a" tag. Which I can not understand where is coming from. Check the link below to see the example image. Where is "a" tag coming from?

```
$statuslist .= '<div  id="status_'.$statusid.'" class="status_boxes" onclick="reply_click(event)">
                   <div style="border-style:none;  border-radius:5px; background-color:'.$userColor.'" >
                      <b>Posted by <a href="user.php?u='.$author.'">'.$author.'</a> '.$postdate.':</b> 
                        '.$statusDeleteButton.' <br />'.$data.'</div>'.$status_replies.'</div>';
```

[image: link to example image]

Comment: Where are you initializing $statuslist? Because you are adding to it by using the .= operator.

Comment: At the begining of php <?php
$statuslist ="";

Comment: You're concatenating `$statuslist` so, maybe you're adding that tag before, please provide more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning with `.=`, so that HTML is appended to whatever is already in `$statuslist`.  Presumably something earlier in the code did

```
$statuslist = '<a>
</a>';
```

If this should start a new value instead of adding to the previous value, change `.=` to `=`.

Comment: There is again an "a" tag  before the first child DIV in <div  id="status_'.$statusid.'" class="status_boxes" onclick="reply_click(event)">  I have uploaded more HTML  in another image

Comment: Maybe you have JavaScript adding them? Do you see them when you do `View Source`?

Comment: How to search in source?

Comment: The same way you search on any web page, use Ctl-f (or Cmd-f on Mac)